# Module Not Found Node Js 'to-fast-properties'

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I have updated my node to latest one.
I have also tried uninstalled and reinstalled the node one time to fix this problem but no success.
I have also run the command `sudo npm install -g to-fast-properties` to install this module.

Can anyone help why this error is still coming?

```
browserify -t babelify app.js -o bundle.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'to-fast-properties'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saurabhchaudhary/www/react-soundplayer/examples/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/lib/types/index.js:23:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

By the I am using react library which I would like to browserify my js code to execute in browser. Is there any other way to do same?

Comment: did you try `npm cache clean && rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install` (from https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/104) ?

Comment: No but when I installed module on the same directory on which i was working, it works